# Fit negative binomial distribution in R

Tags: r

I have a data set derived from the sport Snooker:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1rp6zmv8jwi873s/snooker.csv

Column "playerRating" can take the values from 0 to 1, and describes how good a player is:

- 0: bad player
- 1: good player

Column "suc" is the number of consecutive balls potted by each player with the specific rating.

I am trying to prove 2 things regarding the number of consecutive balls potted until first miss:

1. The distribution of successes follows a negative binomial
2. The number of success depends on the player's worth. ie if a player is really good, he will manage to pot more consecutive balls.

I am using the "fitdistrplus" package to fit my data, however, I am unable to find a way of using the "playerRatings" as input parameters.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please help us help you by providing us with a reproducible example (i.e. code and example data), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for details.

Comment: What question you are trying to answer by "fitting the data"? What are the odds of player scoring considering how often they miss and how likely they will play?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, these are supposedly the first 10 rows of his data set.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra I have edited my question. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: Does this help:  get the mean `playerRating` for each value of `suc` , `for(jj in 1:18) sfoo[jj]<- mean(snook[snook[,3]==(jj-1),2])` ; then `lm(sfoo~I(0:17)` returns intercept and slope `0.510350     0.002649`. From which it may be possible to estimate the binomial coefficients. (or invert that to get lin fit of `suc` as function of   `PlayerRating` )

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, thanks for your help.
how do you get the neg bin coeffs from intercept and slope?